# Basic Multiple Event Probability for a Rubbish Chemist - should be easy

Tags: probability

I was hoping someone could help me with something that surely ought to be simple but I've forgotten how to do it since school. It should just be an extension on the familiar marble in bag problem.
I'm writing a chemistry paper and I'd like to work out the following:

Reaction A + B gives AA, AB or BB

I would like to know the number of times AB comes out if there are:

$6.022 * 10^{23}$ of A

and $9.033 * 10^{23} $ of B in the bag (1.5*A)

Each event is dependent so once a pair is made, they are then removed from the "bag". I will then divide the number of A-B I get by the number of A put in in the first place to get a statistical yield for my reaction with respect to A.

I'm sure there should be an easy way to do this but it has me stuck and I'd really like to be learn how to tackle this (or even where to look for this information)

Thanks, C

Comment: Your question is "If I have $a$ marbles of color A and $b$ marbles of color B and draw two marbles uniformly at random without replacement, what is the probability that we get one A and one B?"  If so, that will simply be $\dfrac{ab}{\binom{a+b}{2}} = \dfrac{2ab}{(a+b)(a+b-1)}$

Comment: Thanks for helping!. That is true for the first pair (and indeed any subsequent) but I'd like to know the total number of times I get one A and one B when I empty all the marbles from the bag, 2 at a time. I feel like there should be some kind of iterative equation to model this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this one is the property known as linearity of expectation. No matter how a bunch of random variables are correlated, the expected value of their sum is the sum of their expected values.

So then, we have $1.25\mathbf{A}$ pairs, each with a probability of $\dfrac{2\cdot \mathbf{A}\cdot 1.5\mathbf{A}}{(\mathbf{A}+1.5\mathbf{A})(\mathbf{A}+1.5\mathbf{A}-1)}\approx \dfrac{3}{6.25}$ of being of type AB. The expected number of pairs of that type is then just the product of the number of pairs and the probability, or approximately $\dfrac{3.75\mathbf{A}}{6.25} = \dfrac35\mathbf{A}$.

What happened to the $-1$ in the formula? Avogadro's number $\mathbf{A}$ is huge, so it basically doesn't matter. If we left it in, it would change the expected number of pairs by less than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help you absolute diamond. 
Am I right in thinking that if I want to work out the probability of aa in this, the denominator in the expression above should remain the same as there are the same number of molecules in the pot. In which case I should write $2⋅A⋅A/(A+1.5A)(A+1.5A−1)≈2/6.25$ Then $1.25A⋅2/6.25 = 0.4A$ so there will be 0.4A incidences of aa. Then doing the same with b.   $2⋅1.5A⋅1.5A/(A+1.5A)(A+1.5A−1)≈4.5/6.25$ so 0.9A incidences of bb. The sum of these is then 1.9A which is more than 1.25A.... What am I missing?

Comment: The doubling only happens for $AB$ - that factor of $2$ is because we're counting both orders $A,B$ and $B,A$. In the other two cases, there's only one order $A,A$ or $B,B$.

Comment: Ah sweet you sorted it. Thanks again .

Comment: In which case if the ratio between the two materials is 1:2 then the maximum statistical yield is 67% (as in the number of $ab$ results divided by the number of $a$ put in) and if the ratio between the materials is 1:3 then the maximum is 75%. This is a curious result as I have a PHD thesis in front of me that suggests that the values should be 80% and 86% respectively. I hope I'm right haha

Comment: Well, I can see where those $80\%$ and $86\%$ numbers are coming from; that's $\frac45$ and $\frac67$. Maybe in that thesis you're looking at, there's something that makes the $b$ count for two each? Or maybe it's just a mistake. There's no way I can tell without the larger context.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that would make it count more than the other material. It's simply the following:
I have materials A and B, there are nA of B with n being 2 or 3.
The reaction couples completely randomly with A +nB giving a quantity of AA, AB and BB,

What is the statistical yield of AB with respect to the quantity of A put in

Comment: So as far as I can see, the model you suggest is valid